# React mousemove event not working as expected

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

In the below slider while click and dragging the slider it should log as true but mousemove event handler logging true and false even though mouseIn state is not changed. Please help me understand this behaviour

https://codesandbox.io/s/slider-fj57bc

Comment: Your first `useEffect` function is adding multiple eventListeners, what is the outcome that you're trying to accomplish? You might need to tweak how you add event listeners

Comment: Can you post your code in the question as well?

Comment: Also, I'm assuming you are trying to recreate a custom slider, I would take a look at how radix-ui has built theres, it's best to use an `<input />` element https://github.com/radix-ui/primitives/blob/main/packages/react/slider/src/Slider.tsx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like the issue is you are not calling `removeEventListener`, which means you are actually creating multiple event listeners for every event. I believe you can update your useEffect as follows to acheive the desired behavior:

```
useEffect(() => {
 function handleMouseUp(e) {
  setMouseIn(false);
 }

function handleMouseMove(e) {
  console.log(mouseIn);
  if (!mouseIn) return;
  setWidth(e);
 }

 window.addEventListener("mouseup", handleMouseUp);
 window.addEventListener("mousemove", handleMouseMove);
 return () => {
  window.removeEventListener("mouseup", handleMouseUp);
  window.removeEventListener("mousemove", handleMouseMove);
 };
}, [mouseIn]);
```

The cleanup function in your code is adding event listeners with the initial value of `mouseup = false` which is never being removed therefore constantly toggling between `true` and `false`. By removing them you ensure that you remove previous event listeners and bind new events anytime `mouseIn` changes.

Comment: Aaah that's a typo. Thanks for helping out